# Error en la migración al usar eloquent en las rutas

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Cuando descargo mi proyecto desde el repositorio en otro ordenador me ocurre un problema al hacer el *php artisan migrate* si uso eloquent en el archivo **routes.php**

En routes tengo lo siguiente:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => App\Page::find(3)->slug //Aquí es donde se genera el error
], function () {
    Route::get('{slug}', [
        'as' => 'course',
        'uses' => 'PublicController@courseSingle'
    ]);
});
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1146 Table 'mi_bd.pages' doesn't exist (SQL: select *
>   from `pages` where `pages`.`id` = 3 and `pages`.`deleted_at` is null
>   limit 1) [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:
>   1146 Table 'mi_bd.pages' doesn't exist

La solución rápida que uso es comentar esa parte de código, hacer el migrate y luego descomentar el código, pero estoy seguro que se debe poder hacer de otra forma.

Gracias!

Comment: Tienes creada la tabla `pages` en tu base de datos?

Comment: No, por eso genera el error. Pero necesito hacer la migración para generar las tablas.

Comment: No entiendo porqué utiliza rutas en la migración. Ahí sólo debería definir las tablas de tu base.

Comment: No uso rutas en la migración. Pero al ejecutar el comando de la migración debe revisar el archivo routes y genera el error cuando se encuentra el Page::find(3)

Comment: Está extraño, probastes con `php artisan migrate:refresh`?

Comment: Sí, genera el mismo error.

Comment: Cuando ejecutas la migración no son necesarias las rutas, si borras las rutas y ejecutas la migración no debería tirar error y crear todas las tablas. Luego vuelves a agregar las rutas y todo debería servir. :)

Comment: Asumiendo que la solución planteada por Jemonge funcione, no entiendo para qué llamar el slug de un registro específico como prefijo de un grupo derutas, ¿algún motivo en particular para hacerlo?

Comment: @Jemonge como digo en la pregunta, si borro las rutas puedo hacer el migrate sin problemas, pero esto no debería ser así. Tiene que haber alguna forma, no se si haciendo model binding.

Comment: @Shaz Lo quiero llamar porque es un campo dinámico que depende del nombre de la página que ponga el administrador. Por ejemplo primero la página se llama Equipo y después lo cambia a Trabajadores, el slug cambiaría de **test.dev/equipo/juan** a **test.dev/trabajadores/juan**

Comment: La verdad creo que podrías generar esa ruta de otra forma, aunque tendría que conocer el contexto del proyecto completo para entenderlo mejor y proponer algo, pero normalmente por ningún motivo contemplaría un valor de la base de datos en la ruta, el riesgo de errores por la dependencia es muy alto.

Comment: @Shaz totalmente de acuerdo, por eso estaba pensando en hacerlo con model binding pero no se como. Otra opción que se me ocurre es quitar el prefix y pasar otro parámetro, pero repetiría la misma variable en muchos enlaces, lo cual me parece reiterativo...

Comment: Deberías usar `Model Binding /{page}/`

Comment: @dorellango Me puedes mostrar como en una respuesta? Gracias!